# Insert multiple rows into 1 table for each row in another table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a temp table that I want to use to populate another table. For every row in the temp table I want to execute a function that may result in one or more records being generated for the other table.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cur IS SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1;
BEGIN
   FOR rec 
   IN cur
   LOOP
-- Pseudo Code Follows
      FOR result 
        IN somefunction(rec.col1, rec.col2)
        INSERT INTO table2
        (col1, col2, col3, calculated_value)
        VALUES
        (rec.col1, rec.col2, rec.col3, result.calculated_value)
      END LOOP;

   END LOOP;
END;
```

Does this make sense to do it this way?

Can Oracle PL/SQL functions return something iterable like this?

I would normally do this in Perl or Python, but since all the data is in Oracle, I don't want to waste time retrieving the data, calculating it, and then inserting the data, if it can all be done within the database. The temp table will have about 75000 rows, and I expect the second table will have 550000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Create Temporary table in Oracle for one time only (ONCE and only ONCE not every session)
The rows you insert into it are visible only to your session, and are automatically deleted when you end you session ( or end of the transaction, depending on which "ON COMMIT" clause you use).
Example:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
(col1 number,
 col2 DATE,
 col3 varchar2(20)
 )   ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

Now comming to your case:

```
CURSOR C
      IS
       SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM temp_table;
X_calculated_value VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
--Your temporary table should be filled in the session
FOR I IN C
      LOOP
         select somefunction(I.col1, I.col2) into X_calculated_value from dual;
         IF calculated_value ..YourCodition
         THEN
            INSERT INTO table2
        (col1, col2, col3, calculated_value)
        VALUES
        (I.col1, I.col2, I.col3, X_calculated_value)
         ELSE
            //do something also
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: My question was more about the function. Can a function return more than one result and how do you iterate over the results if it is possible, to insert into table 2?

Comment: You can get multi value from a function by using a record way like the following: create or replace type Record_Type(x1 number, x2 number, x3 number);
then your function: 
create or replace function get_rec_value return Record_Type
as  
   My_Record Record_Type;
begin
   
   select X1, X2,X3 into My_Record  from Table2 where PutYourConditionToHaveOneRecResult ;

   return(My_Record);  
end;